# Magento 2 : Debug Xml

Tags: magento2, xml

I need to work with xml and something doesn't work same it's always.

Is there a way to see errors in xml syntax, calls, or something.

I don't see nothing in Magento's log, or even in apache's log.

UPDATE

My question is in general, because all the time i did something in Magento 2 that implies an xml is horrible.
Now the problem is with the ui_component following [this guide](https://www.maximehuran.fr/en/create-adminhtml-grid-with-magento-2/)

Maybe the ui_component layout isn't load, but i don't see the "add New" button.

Comment: can you describe what you have try and not working same as they.

Answer (score 0):

Most IDE's have syntax checking for XML files. They will underline in red any issues you have in your xml markup. This will help you prevent any errors when writing your xml config and layout files.